# Pandas saving single record into multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a CSV file but then when I save the file using .to_csv(), every record is stored as multiple lines and not a single line

```
toxicity,male,female,homosexual_gay_or_lesbian,black,white,asian,latino,jewish,muslim,christian,comment_text
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,People that produce wealth?
Here's some wealth for you.
 girl is picked up for criminal trespass. She is put on probation

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"the increase on oahu was primarily due to higher costs

it's heco running their inefficient gas
```

but I want the records to be stored in a single line like this,

```
toxicity,male,female,homosexual_gay_or_lesbian,black,white,asian,latino,jewish,muslim,christian,comment_text
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,People that produce wealth? Here's some wealth for you.  girl is icked up for criminal trespass. She is put on probation
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"the increase on oahu was primarily due to higher costs it's heco running their inefficient gas
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the data stored in a dataframe? is so, can you please give a concrete example? cause what you wrote it is hard to understand what are the rows and what are the columns

Comment: Hey, It is stored as dataframe. And I figured out the solution. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem! It turns out that the `comment_text` has some Unicode characters that were causing problems because of encoding-related issues.

I found this to be a solution

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.encode('unicode_escape').\
                             decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```